# Why do we need a temporary object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

As I have seen in many examples, first they allocate memory for the temporary object and later the same object is assigned to self. For example, I have a code snippet here :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   Movie *newMovie = [[[Movie alloc] initWithTitle:@"Iron Man"
                                    boxOfficeGross:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:650000000.00] 
                                           summary:@"Smart guy makes cool armor"] autorelease];
   self.movie = newMovie;
 }
```

Why cant we perform like:

```
self.movie =[[[Movie alloc] initWithTitle:@"Iron Man"
                           boxOfficeGross:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:650000000.00]
                                  summary:@"Smart guy makes cool armor"] autorelease];
```

Comment: As far as I know both are exactly equivalent.  I might be wrong, though.

Comment: Looks like both mean the same.., Anyway thanks for the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are essentially the same. They adhere to the ownership clause – You release what create/retain. The difference, though not so obvious here, is that the time it takes for an autoreleased object to be released. Say, if loads of such autoreleased objects lingered around in the memory, this could create memory problems. If we released them and their retain count is zero, they are immediately deallocated and memory is freed up.

Comment: I didn knew that !! I just thought using AutoRelease is better and the memory is deallocated automatically

Comment: @KPK Not using autorelease pools is premature optimisation. If memory is a concern, chances are you also need to deallocate framework-returned autoreleased objects as well, and you cannot simply send them `-release`.

Comment: Try to avoid autorelease wherever possible, if you KNOW the scope of your variables then be as efficient as possible and alloc and release when you know you are done with them. I see too many developers use autorelease pools as a way to make their lives simpler, however it is just lazy and can lead to large memory footprints if you are performing lots of allocs in a single run loop.

Comment: Releasing at the end of the first snippet is wrong. The object is already autoreleased, so releasing later would be an overrelease. Also, under normal circumstances, whether an object was released or autoreleased makes no difference to when it will be deallocated if you're using this pattern. The setter will retain the object and keep it around either way.

Comment: @Chuck I totally missed that autorelease.

Comment: The last sentence is not correct. GC is kind of tricky and will not release things immediately after their retain count becomes 0.

Comment: @Anton: He's clearly talking about the retain-release memory management model. Garbage collection is irrelevant.

Comment: @Chuck: Sure. I just wanted to mention that the memory is not freed up immediately.

Comment: @Anton: But under normal circumstances, the memory for an object *is* freed immediately upon receiving its final release.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the temporary object. Your suggestion is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

However, if you need to set properties or call methods after creating the object, using a temporary object may be a little nicer than calling `self.movie` multiple times:

```
Movie *newMovie = [[[Movie alloc] initWithTitle:@"Iron Man" boxOfficeGross:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:650000000.00] summary:@"Smart guy makes cool armor" ] autorelease];
newMovie.rating = 4;
[newMovie fetchImageFromServer];
self.movie = newMovie;
```

Personally, I do not use `autorelease` in that scenario, but that's more a style preference:

```
Movie *newMovie = [[Movie alloc] initWithTitle:@"Iron Man" boxOfficeGross:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:650000000.00] summary:@"Smart guy makes cool armor" ];
newMovie.rating = 4;
[newMovie fetchImageFromServer];
self.movie = newMovie;
[newMovie release];
```